# Linear program with quadratic (L2 norm) constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints, qclp

I would like to solve an optimization problem of the type

$$ \min_x x^T c, \quad s.t. \|x\|_2 \leq k \; \land \; a \leq x_i \leq b \; \forall i$$

efficiently (note the quadratic norm constraint), where $x, c \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $a, b, k \in\mathbb{R}$. The dimension $N$ is large, i.e., in the ten thousands. How would I do this?

In case this makes it any easier: in my particular example, $a=0$, i.e., all entries of $x$ need to be positive. This does not hold for $c$, though.

[This 6-year old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648960/linear-programming-with-one-quadratic-equality-constraint) is probably related, but answers there are inconclusive, and my case is less general. (The $H$ in that question is simply the identity matrix in my problem.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is a second order cone programming (SOCP) problem.  There are specialized interior point solvers for these kinds of problems that can be very efficient.

Comment: If only one knew all the special keywords for the myriad different types of optimization problems...

Comment: For future reference: SOCP programming is implemented e.g. in Stephen Boyd's CVX toolbox. http://cvxr.com/cvx/

Answer (score 3):

Let me give a solution for more general constraints: $\|x\|_2 \le k$, $x_i \in [a_i,b_i]$ for all $i$, for some prescribed numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$ such that $a_i \le b_i$ for all $i$. That is, my solution doesn't require the $a_1 = \ldots = a_n$ or $b_1 = b_2 = \ldots = b_n$.

---

By Lagrange dualizaiton, one can write.
$$
\begin{split}
\min_{\|x\|_2 \le k,\; x \in \Pi_i [a_i,b_i]}x^Tc &= \sup_{\lambda \ge 0}\min_{x \in \Pi_i [a_i,b_i]}x^Tc - \lambda(k^2 - x^Tx)\\
&= \sup_{\lambda \ge 0}-k^2\lambda + \inf_{x \in \Pi_i [a_i,b_i]}\lambda x^Tx + x^Tc.
\end{split}
$$

Now, for fixed $\lambda \ge 0$, the inner problem is solved by taking

$$
x_i(\lambda) :=\begin{cases}-\dfrac{c_i}{2\lambda},&\mbox{ if }-\dfrac{c_i}{2\lambda} \le a_i \le -\dfrac{c_i}{2\lambda} \le b_i,\\a_i,&\mbox{ if }-\dfrac{c_i}{2\lambda} \le a_i,\\b_i,&\mbox{ if} -\dfrac{c_i}{2\lambda} \ge b_i.\end{cases}
\tag{1}
$$

Thus the original problem can be written as

$$
\min_{\lambda \ge 0, \|x(\lambda)\|_2 \le k} -k^2\lambda +\lambda\|x(\lambda)\|^2 + x(\lambda)^Tc = \min_{\lambda \ge 0, \|x(\lambda)\|_2 \le k} x(\lambda)^Tc,
$$

which is a **one-dimensional** optimization problem in $\lambda$. Once this is solved, the solution to the original problem is obtained via formula (1).

Comment: Ah, that's a very clever approach! Seeing that the resulting 1-D optimization problem is nonlinear, nonsmooth, nonconvex and nonlinearly constrained, one would then use some generic global optimization method?

Comment: Yes, that's what you'd do. In one dimension, life is embarassingly easy, and so you should get a good approximation to the solution solution after a few iterations of a reasonable generic algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Is this somehow related to the SOCP approach mentioned by Brian, or is it a completely different method?